# Testdisk won’t list files for an ext4 partition inside a LVM inside a LUKS partition

Tags: lvm, data-recovery, ext4

I have accidentally deleted a file that I want to recover. The partition is an ext4 partition inside an LVM partition that is encrypted with dm-crypt/LUKS.

The encrypted LUKS partition is: /dev/sda2
which contains a physical volume, with a single volume group, mapped to: /dev/mapper/system
And the logical volume, the ext4 partition is mapped to:
/dev/mapper/system-home

A `# testdisk /dev/mapper/system-home` will notice it as an ext4 partition but tells me that the partition seems damaged when I try to list the files. If I `# testdisk /dev/mapper/system` it will detect all the partitions, but the same happens if I try to list their files.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a known bug? I have searched but haven’t found any clue.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing something wrong.

`testdisk` is meant to operate on and recover disk partitions, which is not the problem you're having. Most likely you want to use its companion tool `photorec` instead, which recovers deleted files (and not just photos).

Comment: `df` says that `/dev/mapper/system-home` is mounted at `home`. `blkid` tells me that `/dev/mapper/system-home` has `TYPE="ext4"`, do you know what can be wrong in this case? I have listed files from ext4 partitions before, I do not see why testdisk won’t let me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home - 210 GB / 196 GiB 

[Proceed ]
```

choose the default

```
[None   ] Non partitioned media
```

if you choose  :

```
[Intel  ] Intel/PC partition
```

will lead in error that you describe